# react animation animated component undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a circular animation like a wave and i found that [code](https://snack.expo.io/@bidah/animate-react-native-with-popmotion-pure-(keyframes-&-stagger)) on the internet. And i converted and changed it with react hooks but then this code does not work correctly. Where is my mistake?

```
const constructAnimations = [...Array(COUNT).keys()].map(() => initialPhase);

export default function SearchAnimation() {
  const [stateAnimations, setStateAnimations] = useState(constructAnimations);

  useEffect(() => {
    const actions = Array(COUNT).fill(
      keyframes({
        values: [initialPhase, { scale: 2, opacity: 0 }],
        duration: DURATION,
        loop: Infinity,
        yoyo: Infinity,
      })
    );

    stagger(actions, DURATION / COUNT).start((animations) => {
      setStateAnimations({ animations });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {[stateAnimations].map(({ opacity, scale }, index) => {
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={index}
            style={[
              styles.circle,
              {
                transform: [{ scale }],
                opacity,
              },
            ]}
          />
        );
      })}
      <View style={styles.midCircle}>
        <FontAwesome name="phone" style={styles.icon} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Searching</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also the error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.getValue')
This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at SearchAnimation.js:33)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
```

Comment: if possible, post the whole app reproducing the problem on https://snack.expo.io

Comment: Here is the whole Animations component that i converted: 
 https://snack.expo.io/5KH1_4QsV @KetanRamteke

Comment: Also you can find a link for original class based componenet from question page. @KetanRamteke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems I've found.

The first is that the class based example you linked maps over the `stateAnimations` array, but you map over `[stateAnimations]`.
So since `stateAnimations` is already an array you don't need to
surround it with another array. If you fix this the error you posted in your question goes away.

I also found that the working class-based example uses version `8.6.2` of `popmotion` and the code in the example apparently doesn't work anymore for version `9+`.

So after downgrading to `8.6.2` the following code worked for me:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Animated, Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { keyframes, stagger, tween } from "popmotion";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const COUNT = 4;
const DURATION = 5000;
const initialPhase = { scale: 0, opacity: 1 };
const constructAnimations = [...Array(COUNT).keys()].map(() => initialPhase);

export default function SearchAnimation() {
  const [stateAnimations, setStateAnimations] = useState(constructAnimations);

  useEffect(() => {
    const actions = Array(COUNT).fill(
      keyframes({
        values: [initialPhase, { scale: 2, opacity: 0 }],
        duration: DURATION,
        loop: Infinity,
        yoyo: Infinity,
      })
    );

    stagger(actions, DURATION / COUNT).start((animations) => {
      setStateAnimations(animations);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {stateAnimations.map(({ opacity, scale }, index) => {
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={index}
            style={[
              styles.circle,
              {
                transform: [{ scale }],
                opacity,
              },
            ]}
          />
        );
      })}
      <View style={styles.midCircle}>
        <FontAwesome name="phone" style={styles.icon} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Searching</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const getCircle = (radius, backgroundColor = "gold") => ({
  backgroundColor,
  width: radius * 2,
  height: radius * 2,
  borderRadius: radius,
  position: "absolute",
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  circle: getCircle(100),
  midCircle: {
    ...getCircle(75),
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That is helped me a lot.