# BorderBottom added top of the view React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to add a border to the bottom of the `<View>` (like `<hr>`) for that reason i added that code to my style:

```
export default function Chat() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.inner}>
        <CircleCard />
        <CircleCard />
        <CircleCard />
        <CircleCard />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inner: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "85%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flex: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "black",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

But this code draw the border to top of the  instead of Bottom.

Also The CircleCard component:

```
export default function CircleCard() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        source={require("../assets/games/Among-us.png")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { width: 60, height: 60, margin: 5, marginTop: 10 },
  imageStyle: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    overflow: "hidden",
    resizeMode: "stretch",
    borderRadius: 140,
  },
});
```

How can I fix it?

Note: I added a negative marginTop to my styles.inner but than when i add a new component all page broken.

[image]

Here is what i want to make:

[image]

Comment: can you post the ui image that you are wanting to achieve: does this one works? https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/blessed-blueberries

Comment: I have a topnavtab. Does that breake the style? I added an ui from android 9 to main page. Still same problem exist a black border appear on top instead of bottom @KetanRamteke

Comment: Your borderBottomColor is set to white (not black as your goal).
The border on top might be related to topnav

Comment: Sorry i did not add the changes. I changed the color from white to black. I am adding that info to main page.

Comment: In your `inner` style you're trying to use `height` and `flex: 1` at the same time. Try removing `flex: 1`

Comment: head to chat tab: https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/toptabbartransition

Comment: @KetanRamteke. You are insane :). Thanks i solved my problem. I wonder that do you code whole of the that code from my image ?

Comment: @Leo, glad it helped. Happy coding :)

Comment: can i ask another questions that does not solved for 3 days.@KetanRamteke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65567310/react-animation-animated-component-undefined @KetanRamteke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Working app : [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/toptabbartransition)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function Chat() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.inner}>
        <CircleCard />
        <CircleCard />
        <CircleCard />
        <CircleCard />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function CircleCard() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        source={{
          uri:
            'https://www.graphicpie.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/red-among-us-png-1684x2048.png',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    margin: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 30,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    borderRadius: 140,
  },
  inner: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    /**
     * i guess "rgba(21,21,21,0.2)" looks better than then plain "black"
     * borderBottomColor: "rgba(21,21,21,0.2)",
     */
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
});
```